# How to get server-side registry access from COM object instanciated by php?

Tags: .net, php, com, registry

On the server I would like to call into a dll from php. Using a COM object. This wasn't a problem, until I tried to use some WPF features.

I get the following error:

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'com_exception' with message 'Source:
>   mscorlib Description: Requested
>   registry access is not allowed.'

Thru the ProcMon utility I've found that only 1 access denied is raised on

> HKU\S-1-5-20\Software\Microsoft\Wisp\Pen\SysEventParameters

This key is used for some ["Erasing by Using the Pen"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms702533(VS.85).aspx) settings. I do not do anything with this class, It seems that it's called on initialization or something.

this process is call by php-cgi.exe from user NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE. In regedit.exe I saw that this user has access to the key.

Is should be possible to use WPF on the server, right? I think I have to lower the security on some point somewhere.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a single setting in IIS7. I changed the Anonymous Authentication Credentials from NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE to Application Pool Identity and the problem was fixed.